# How to print dict data in html if i submit form using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms

I am new in Django and I am trying to create a short url website and I short the url without page refresh using Ajax and I create a unique url in my view.py but I don't know how to print the create url using `JsonResponse` please tell me how I will do it

index.html:

```
    <form method="POST"  id="shorten" class="form-inline">{% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="Your URL Here" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" id="url"/>
        <button id="submit" class="btn-captcha" style="display: flex;"  type="submit"><img src={% static "img/right-arrow.png" %} alt=""/></button>

        <div> {{url}}<div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit','#shorten',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/shorturl/',
        data:{
            url:$('#url').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken : $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success:function(){
            alert("ok")
        }    
    });    
});
</script>
```

views.py:

```
def shorturl(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = request.POST.get('url')
        obj = userurltable(url = url)
        obj.save()
        obj2 = userurltable.objects.last()
        url_id = obj2.id 
        code = short_url.encode_url(url_id)
        shortened_url = settings.BASEURL + code
        dic = {"url": shortened_url }
        # I want to send this dic to my html page and 
        # print the url in html I don't wanna use render 
        # because I am submitting the form using ajax
```

so how would I print short url in `<div>{{url}}</div>` without page refresh ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all assign an id to your div:

```
<div id="div_id">  <div>
```

Then in your view return a JsonResponse:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def shorturl(request):
    data = {} 
    if request.method == 'POST':
       # your shortened code
       data = {"url": shortened_url}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

And now you put the shortened url into your div and input:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: '/shorturl/',
    data:{
        url:$('#url').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken : $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data){
         $('#div_id').append(data['url']); // or data.url
         $('#shorten input').val(data['url']); 
    }
});
```

Comment: sir can you help me on other problem please

Comment: sir i need help by show photos so can you msg me on whatsapp